# Thai e-visa hotel reservation document

Tags: visas, thailand

I am trying to request a Tourist visa for Thailand. The embassy requested an additional document requiring me to send: `hotel reservation (the name and last name of the applicant must be mentioned)`. I have a hotel reservation, but in the name of my friend (the document shows that it is a room for 2 adults). So my name is not on the reservation.

So what information should I send (I've already sent the hotel reservation document in the initial visa request)? I assume this should be quite a common case, but I couldn't find anything online regarding this. Should I ask the hotel whether they can add my name to the reservation and give a document showing

Comment: The hotel reservation you sent wasn't acceptable to the Thai authorities as the confirmation didn't contain you as a named guest. So the information you should send is the hotel's confirmation that you will be a registered guest. Trying to get Immigration to change its mind seems like a non-starter. You'll need to get the hotel to issue or amend their confirmation, or, perhaps, you should reserve at another hotel that will include your name in the confirmation.